# can the following be achieved through Streams?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a List of elements:

```
1, 2, 3, 4...
```

And I have a starting element, let's say `a`.
I want to compute `f(1, a) = b` and then feed the output of this function f i.e. `b` along with the next element in the list `2` back into the same function.

So the sequence would be:

```
f(1, a)=b
f(2, b)=c
f(3, c)=d
f(4, d)=e
```

And the final output is `e`.

Is there a way to write this in Java 8 using streams?

Comment: Well, you could do this with just a plain `map` with a stateful mapping function, but the proper functional operation you are describing is often called a [`reduce` operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce). Your reducer will simply have to have a more complex input&output type

Comment: understood. So something like this would work: `list.stream()
                .reduce('a', (partialResult, element) -> function(partialResult, element));`

Comment: Its not an ideal fit for streams, since their API is designed with multithreading and spliterators in mind. So the methods wont easily allow you to write transformations that require results of "the previous transformation" in a sequential chain. Its possible though, that for sure. Unless you have to use streams, I would suggest you stick to a regular loop here - it will be easier to write and more importantly also read and understand.

Comment: @the_stack_over_flew In theory yes, but with a lot of caveats: Only if you require it to be `.sequential()` (so it doesnt start reducing at multiple spots simultanously, eventually merging them) and only if the type of `a, b, c, d, e` is also `int` (otherwise you need the overload that splits accumulator and combiner).

Comment: Thing is, streams are designed for multithreading in mind. The API is written in a way that the a design goal is that processing a stream is done from multiple regions simultanously. Not just from start to end. Suppose a range like `1, ..., 10`. Then it might start one thread for the range `1, ... , 3` and another thread starts at `4, ... 6` and a third thread at `7, ..., 10` and eventually their results are combined. This is what the `Spliterator` is used for. And your algorithm naturally doesnt allow something like that - so you have to force the stream to not do this. Or you get bad results

Comment: I do need it to be sequential - the codebase I am working with strictly seems to use Java-8 for everything. Will think over this a bit.

Comment: Okay, I understand why reduce should not be used in this case - the unnecessary overloading of combiner for parallel execution is unavoidable even though I need it to be sequential. @GACy20 mentioned using stateful function mapping with map.. confused how this would work. Can you elaborate?